# How do I deal with the indicator to compute the cdf of $X_i $with pdf: $f(x;\theta)=\frac{2x}{\theta^2}1_{(0,\theta)}(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am having trouble with the indicator in the following exercise:

**Let  $Y=\max_i {X_i}$ , $i=1...n $ where $X_i $ are independent and identically distributed random variables, with the following pdf: $f(x;\theta)=\frac{2x}{\theta^2}1_{(0,\theta)}(x)$, with  $\theta >0$ a parameter Find the cdf of $X_i$ and  cdf and pdf of $Y$**

The cdf of $X_i$ is
$F_{X_i}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{2z}{\theta^2}1_{(0,\theta)}(z)dz$

I know the $F_{Y}(x)=(F_{X_1}(x))^n$. Once I have $F_{X_1}(x)$, I can just differentiate to find the pdf of $Y$

**I am not sure how to proceed, since I don't know if $\theta  >x $ or $\theta <x$ to write the upper integral limit and if whether I should do a 2-dimensional integral in the $\theta $ vs $ z$ plane. Any ideas?**

Note This is no homework so feel free to help

**Edit**

If $x<0, F_{X_i}(x)=0$

If $0<x<\theta,  1_{(0,\theta)}= 1$ if $0<z<\theta<x$ ;

$F_{X_i}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{2z}{\theta^2}1_{(0,\theta)}(z)dz=?$

Comment: $1_{0,\theta}(z) = 1$ for $0<z<\theta$ and $0$ otherwise. Consider the cases $x<0$, $0<x<\theta$, and $x>\theta$ to evaluate the integral for $F_{X_i}(x)$.

Comment: @user170231 See the edit, How does $0<\theta<z<x$ goes into the integral? Is it a bidimensional integral?

Comment: If $x>\theta$, then$$F_{X_i}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_{X_i}(z)\,dz=\left\{\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^\theta+\int_\theta^x\right\}f_{X_i}(z)\,dz=0+1+0=1$$(forgive the abuse of notation for the integrals)

Comment: @user170231 what about $x=\theta$ or $x=0$? Should't be consider them as well? I found $F_{X_i}(x)=\frac {x^{2n}}{\theta^{2n}}1_{(0,\theta)}(x)+1_{(\theta, +\infty)}$

Comment: I think you mean $F_Y(x)$, not $F_{X_i}(x)$. You can include or exclude those point as you like. $\operatorname{Pr}(X\le0)=\operatorname{Pr}(X<0)$ since $X$ has a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 1):

For $y\in(0,\theta)$ we have
$$
\{Y \leqslant y\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i \leqslant y\}
$$
and hence
$$
F_Y(y):= \mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i \leqslant y\}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb P(X_i\leqslant y) = \left(\frac y\theta\right)^{2n}.
$$
The density is found by differentiating:
$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dy} F_Y(y) = \frac {2n}y \left(\frac y\theta\right)^{2n}\mathsf 1_{(0,\theta)}(x).
$$